# Why is my code not putting in new values for same row index?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a timestamp and a user number, the user can input their number in multiple times for different days. I am trying to print this to a new sheet that prints the name, the id and put a 1 in the column for the day that they signed in.

There is a counter variable for the entries that have for multiple accounts, so if that's the case I iterate over the sign in list again and find where the number is the same but the days are different. Yet when I try to set the value of the daySheet in the second if statement it uses the first day and not the second one in the list.
An Example of the data I use:
12/14/19  test1
12/20/19  test1

And what it writes in the google sheet:
row 11:     column 14:     column 20:
 test1          1 
                1
I am very confused and wondering if there is a simpler method I should be using or if I am thinking of this in the wrong way?

```
for(var i = 0; i < sheetLength; i++){
signInLN = sheet.getRange(i+1,3).getValue();
      if(counter > 1){//2nd if
        for(var k = 1; k <= sheetLength; k++){//2nd for loop
          //outer for loop is i
          //inner for loop is k
      var date2 = signInSheet.getRange(k+1,1).getValue().toString();//time stamp in sign in sheet
      var month2 = date2.slice(4,7);
      var day2 = Number(date2.slice(8,10));
      Logger.log(day+": Days "+i+" :I");
      var year = Number(date2.slice(11,15));
          if(signInLN == signInSheet.getRange(k+1,3).getValue() && day != day2){//if lunch number is the same and the days are different
            //lunch numbers are the same, dates are different so add to the k value
            daySheet.getRange(k+10,day+3).setValue(1);
          }
        }//2nd for loop

      //2nd if
      }else if(currentCell.isBlank()){
      daySheet.getRange(i+10, 2).setValue(fullName);//set name to first cell     
      //set PI to second cell
      daySheet.getRange(i+10,3).setValue(pI);
      daySheet.getRange(i+10,day+3).setValue(1);      
      }

    }
```

Comment: That's a pretty complicated explanation.  I think I'd need to see the spreadsheet and even then I'm not sure that I'd understand.  I think your going to have to do a little more focusing in your [mcve].  Which probably means working with your debugger.

Comment: You are setting `daySheet.getRange(k+10,day+3).setValue(1);` probably instead you wanted to set `daySheet.getRange(k+10,day+3).setValue(day2);`? If not, please explain bettwe and maybe provide screenshots from the desired output and the actual output.